# Difference in the parameters between Liferay Resource and Action URLs

Tags: url-rewriting, liferay, liferay-6, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I need to create a custom url filter (with [tuckey.org](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)) for resource URL in liferay portal, but I don't know how to distinguish URL created by liferay with @ResourceMapping annotation and the same created with @ActionMapping.
Liferay adds to action and resource URLs some parameters by default. I want to apply my filter only to resource links. Please help me to understand a difference between these URLs.

Thanks a lot for the advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All resource requests have the request-param `p_p_lifecycle=2` in their url, whilst action requests have `p_p_lifecycle=1` and render requests `p_p_lifecycle=0` (which is the default and often omitted)